# luatex tex.print does not trigger process_input_buffer callback?

Tags: luatex, printing, callback

I've defined a new LaTeX command to randomize itemize-like lists using LuaLaTeX like this:

```
\newcommand*\Randomize{%
    \directlua{%
        questions.itemstbl = {""}
        luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", questions.collect_lines, "collect_lines")
    }%
}
```

The Lua code simply collects all lines (items) between `\Randomize` and `\EndRandomize`, which prints the shuffled table of collected items:

```
\newcommand*\EndRandomize{%
    \directlua{tex.print(questions.shuffleTable(questions.itemstbl))}%
}
```

The callback is finally removed by `collect_lines` when it finds the `\EndRandomize` line.

This works like a charm with the following direct input:

```
\begin{itemize}
\Randomize
    \item some text
    \item more text
    \item another text
\EndRandomize
\end{itemize}
```

Problem arises when I try to read (using Lua) such environments from a .tex file and print (show) them using `tex.print`. It seems that LuaTeX does not trigger this data processing callback while doing `tex.print`, so `\Randomize` command does not work (without `\Randomize` it works).

Is there a simple solution for this problem? I'm thinking of generating a temp .tex file with all read itemize-like environments and then `\input` this file, such that the callback is triggered. But I'm trying to avoid the disk rw latency.

Comment: Hm, can you show the mwe that doesn't  work ?

Comment: Here follows a link to a Overleaf project showing a MWE [link](https://www.overleaf.com/read/wfqbtmtqhkxs). What didn't work is if, instead of typing the environment "question" directly, I use several `tex.print` commands to produce the same env content.

Comment: Remark: `\scantokens` doesn't work either. So either stick with temporary TeX file (side note, while it touches the disk, I don't think TeX normally flushes the disk write before continuing anyway, and the operating system should be able to cache the content), or simply manually call your callbacks before `tex.print` (which only works if both the callback and the code that `tex.print` is managed by you)